# How to view pending device driver installations Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I am getting a UAC prompt after boot for a device driver installation - I'm not sure where this is from however and would like to inspect the command (or possibly remove it) that is causing the driver installation to start.

I assume this is stored somewhere in the registry - could anyone point me at the correct place where this installation is being started from?

Comment: Snoop around using [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) and you'll find it.

Answer (score 0):

Pending operations are located in this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\BackupRestore\KeysNotToRestore
```

and in the current control set such as CurrentControlSet**n** where **n** is the "ccs" in use

It's possible to view all pending operation with the Sysinternals *PendMoves* utility:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556

You may use *PendMoves* in combination with NirSoft's *ServiWin* to check all drivers and how they are started...

*BTW:* you may download and update all Sysinternals utilities (as well as NirSoft utilities) with *WSCC* utility http://www.kls-soft.com/wscc/index.php

Hope this help. Let us know.

Comment: Unfortunately that only shows file operations that are to be performed on the next boot, it doesn’t indicate registry operations, service, or driver changes. `:-(` Like Amazed said, Pending Autoruns will be necessary to see what is set to be run, followed by research to figure out what they are doing (it depends on the app). That plus `PendingFileRenameOperations` should do the trick (at least *most* of the time).

Comment: :-\ You're right Synetech. So, instead the user may look at Process Monitor with the option "enable boot logging" combined with filters option...

Comment: Another option is to try some of those “installation monitoring programs”. They will take a snapshot of the system before and after and compare, but of course that doesn’t really help in this case. However, some installation monitors actually hook into the system and monitor changes, so that *would* help (I recall one that starts with a ‘Z’).

Comment: Installation monitoring software? May be TotalUninstall (shareware but free for 30 days...) Also take a look at System Explorer: it's possible to create a snap shot of registry and/or files and compare them.

Comment: I meant *ZSoft Uninstaller*. It was the one of the best I tried because it hooked the system like Process Monitor, but unlike Process Monitor, instead of just showing everything, it is specifically meant to show changes.

Comment: Looks nice! Thank you for this information Synetech.